# How to skip Jenkins CI trigger on specific file changes in Gitlab?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline project for running my CI. Gitlab is my source control repo. I want to skip Jenkins build trigger when change is pushed on a specific files. Is there a way to do so?
Example: These are the files in my source code repo

```
Jenkinsfile 
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt 
file4.txt
```

I do not want build to be triggered when there is a change in *file4.txt*. 
Is there a way I can achieve it?

Comment: What's the context for this requirement? Why not use e.g. [the CI-skip plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ci-skip) to allow you to skip builds from the commit message?

Comment: I tried using this option. It was available under Advance Column of Build Trigger. I checked the box then made a commit with [ci skip] commit message. The build still got triggered.

Answer (score -1):

Got it. CI-Skip Plugin solves it. There was a mistake in CI-Skip README file though. They have mentioned the keyword to be [ci skip] whereas the keyword in [ci-skip]

Comment: This *isn't* an answer to the question you actually asked. It tells you how to skip a build for a specific commit based on the message, which is *not* the same as how to skip a commit based on the files that changed. Although this may solve your problem, it doesn't answer your question.